# Featured image for product listings, but another image as the product image?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, post-thumbnails

I want to show a different image of products listing on the home page of the site, not the featured image but when customers click on the products then it should show the featured image on the product page. The site is on woocoommerce is there any way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: The products on the homepage are usually displayed thanks to the theme. The theme is coded to grab the featured image of the product post. You will need to re-code your theme differently so that it grabs a different image.